# Saving text file in its entirety

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-c++, c++-cli

I need help in coding the proper way to save a text file's contents.  So far, I've managed to save and create a text file, but when I open it, it's always empty.   I am using Visual Studio 2012 and creating a Windows form with c++-CLI.

This is what I have:

```
private: System::Void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
          {
  IO::Stream^ myStream;
  SaveFileDialog^ saveFileDialog1 = gcnew SaveFileDialog;
  saveFileDialog1->Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt";
  saveFileDialog1->FilterIndex = 1;
  saveFileDialog1->RestoreDirectory = true;
  if ( saveFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK )
  {
     if ( (myStream = saveFileDialog1->OpenFile()) != nullptr )
     {

        // Code to write the stream goes here.
        myStream->Close();
     }
  }
}
```

Basically, I'm trying to achieve the code below, the only thing different is that I am using c++-CLI not c# and instead of writing some text in the file as (bw.Write("Example text file.") does, I would want the text file to save my text box values in my windows form, so something like bw.Write(txtTextBox1->Text).  But as far as I'm concerned, c++ doesn't use those same commands c# does.

```
SaveFileDialog sgd = new SaveFileDialog();
sfd.Filter = "Text File|*.txt";
sfd.FileName = "My Text File";
sfd.Title = "Save Text File";
if (sfd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    string path = sft.FileName;
    BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(File.Create(path));
    bw.Write("Example text file.");
    bw.Dispose();
}
```

Here are some images of my program.  I've also included a picture of the print preview button.  I'd basically like for my save button to save a text file with the contents that my print preview displays.

[image: Windows Form]
[image: Print Preview]

Comment: You're probably saving the file as Unicode, but not reading it back as such.

Comment: What's with the screenshots? How do they pertain to the question at all? As far as the question goes: you can write exactly the same thing in C++/CLI as you have written in C#. So why doesn't the C++ code look like the C# code? The code you posted in C++ doesn't ever write anything, so it's not much of a surprise that the result is an empty file. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Finally, don't forget to use `using` to dispose `IDisposable` objects, like your dialog and the `BinaryWriter`.

Comment: By the way, speaking of `BinaryWriter`: even in the C# code, that's suspect, as `BinaryWriter` isn't very suitable for writing text files. Use `StreamWriter` instead (both C# and C++/CLI).

Comment: @PeterDuniho could you post an example on how to make the save button write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why anyone would want to implement a Forms program in C++/CLI is beyond me. C++/CLI is wonderful for many things, but for something that is purely managed (like the Forms API), I think C# is better. There are more code examples to draw from, and the syntax is generally more concise and convenient.

That said, here is a C++/CLI version of the C# code you included, with the small change that it uses `StreamWriter` instead of `BinaryWriter`:

```
SaveFileDialog^ sfd = gcnew SaveFileDialog();

try
{
    sfd->Filter = "Text File|*.txt";
    sfd->FileName = "My Text File";
    sfd->Title = "Save Text File";
    if (sfd->ShowDialog() == DialogResult::OK)
    {
        String^ path = sfd->FileName;
        StreamWriter^ writer = gcnew StreamWriter(File::Create(path));
        try
        {
            writer->Write("Example text file.");
        }
        finally
        {
            delete writer;
        }
    }
}
finally
{
    delete sfd;
}
```

Note that other than some minor syntax differences and the lack of C#'s `using` convenience idiom, it is basically identical to the C# code. You will see similar parallels for the rest of your implementation. C++/CLI uses (or at least, *can* use) exactly the same methods that are used in C#.

Comment: For some reason on the StreamWriter^, writer, StreamWriter, and File words are all underlined as an error.  For StreamWriter^ and writer it says undefined, for StreamWriter it says expected a type specifier and for File it says Error name followed by :: must be a class or namespace name.  Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have `using namespace System::IO;` in the .h or .cpp?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  I understand that c# would be a far better alternative, but my professor gave us this assignment.

Comment: Do you know what is the equivalent of  & vbCrLf & to write to a new line?  It seems all my text is saved but on the same line.  How do I add a line break to the writer?

Comment: Normally, you just call the `WriteLine()` method instead of `Write()`. But if you have need to output the line-break characters explicitly, you can use `Environment.NewLine`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative to the C# code...

Writes text to a file using the UTF-8 encoding of the Unicode character set (which is the 
character set the .NET Strings use):

```
private: System::Void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
{
    SaveFileDialog^ saveFileDialog1 = gcnew SaveFileDialog;
    saveFileDialog1->Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt";
    saveFileDialog1->FilterIndex = 1;
    saveFileDialog1->RestoreDirectory = true;
    if ( saveFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK )
    {
       File::WriteAllText(saveFileDialog1->FileName, "Example text file.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Where would I place this line of code? I've replaced the line writer->Write("Example text file.");  with your code, but when I click save it says empty path name is not legal once typing the file name, location, and clicking save.